# Parse result of XML -> XML2JS ->JSON.stringify using JQ

Tags: node.js, json, jq, stringify, xml2js

I have a file created by doing an XHR fetch of XML and parsing it through the node module `xlm2js` and then `JSON.stringify`.  It has about 700 *segments* of two basic types. This is an edited version of the file with one *segment* of each type:

```
{
  "NewDataSet": {
    "Table": [
      {
        "SegmentID": [
          "2342"
        ],
        "StationID": [
          "005es00045:_MN_Stn"
        ],
        "SegmentName": [
          "I-5 NB MP0.45 @ SR-14"
        ],
        "SegmentType": [
          "2"
        ],
        "SegmentLength": [
          "1135"
        ],
        "MinimumLanesReporting": [
          "0.5"
        ],
        "CalculationThreshold": [
          "30"
        ],
        "CalculationPeriod": [
          "2"
        ],
        "MinimumSamples": [
          "3"
        ],
        "SegmentMaximumFilter": [
          "774"
        ],
        "SegmentMinimumFilter": [
          "12"
        ],
        "StandardDeviationSamples": [
          "15"
        ],
        "StandardDeviationMultiplier": [
          "1.96"
        ],
        "UseStandardDeviationFilter": [
          "false"
        ],
        "IsActive": [
          "true"
        ]
      },
      {
        "SegmentID": [
          "3051"
        ],
        "BeginningDcuID": [
          "584"
        ],
        "EndDcuID": [
          "589"
        ],
        "SourceSystem": [
          "TravelTime"
        ],
        "SegmentName": [
          "OR212 at SE 242nd Ave to OR212 at SE Foster Rd"
        ],
        "SegmentType": [
          "1"
        ],
        "SegmentLength": [
          "100"
        ],
        "CalculationThreshold": [
          "60"
        ],
        "CalculationPeriod": [
          "10"
        ],
        "MinimumSamples": [
          "3"
        ],
        "SegmentMaximumFilter": [
          "3600"
        ],
        "SegmentMinimumFilter": [
          "50"
        ],
        "StandardDeviationSamples": [
          "20"
        ],
        "StandardDeviationMultiplier": [
          "1.96"
        ],
        "UseStandardDeviationFilter": [
          "true"
        ],
        "IsActive": [
          "true"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I need to ignore the `"SegmentType":["2"]` segments and extract `SegmentID`, `SegmentName`, `BeginningDcuID`, `EndingDcuID`, and `SegmentLength` from the type 1 segments where `IsActive` is `true`.

I can list the file with `jq "."` but any attempt at other operations with jq fail, usually with the message:

> 'jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '[' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at , line 1:'

Any suggestions for jq syntax changes or `xml2js` parameter changes to make this work would be outstandingly helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use double quotes for quoting an argument if there is nothing in it that you want the shell to expand.

```
$ jq '.NewDataSet.Table[]
| select(.SegmentType[0] != "2" and .IsActive[0] == "true")
| (.SegmentID, .SegmentName, .BeginningDcuID, .EndingDcuID, .SegmentLength)[0]' file
"3051"
"OR212 at SE 242nd Ave to OR212 at SE Foster Rd"
"584"
null
"100"
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't add the returns to the post because I wasn't sure if they would affect the JQ parsing.  Obviously not.